Sci-fi book series where telepathic greys take over Earth
I'm looking for the title of a sci-fi book series where telepathic greys take over Earth. The greys use humans to raise their young by slowly sucking the life out of them. In the book, a guy named Phil falls in love with a grey that helps them fight the greys. I believe there is a ship called the Rusty Turret. The North Koreans also helped the greys take over Earth.
I listened to it on YouTube.

In roughly which year/s did you listen to this on YouTube? And do you know how many books there were in the series?

Thanks so much LogicDictates, I listened to it this year 2024 I don't remember how many books were in the series. I don't remember the author either. It starts off with the main character upset that his wife is in the bed bonded to the alien kid, then he leaves her to join the space military

@DK-P418 - If you're the author of this question, please merge your accounts by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to post comments in this thread, edit this question without approval from other users, and mark an answer as accepted, if one is posted. Right now, you can't do any of those things, because the site doesn't recognise you as the author of the question.

This must surely be the Freedom's Fire series by Bobby Adair, a six-book series (plus a prequel) published between 2017 and 2018.
The premise is indeed that the Grays, and another alien race known as the Trogs (short for troglodytes), had been assisted by North Korea in invading the Earth. The protagonist of the books is a Major Dylan Kane, but as recalled by the OP, another major character fighting for Earth against the Grays, is named Phil. Their spaceship however, is called the Rusty Turd, rather than the Rusty Turret.
The cover blurb for the first book in the series, Freedom's Fire, gives the summary:

War in the Heavens for Freedom on Earth The first interstellar war, a
generation ago, left humanity enslaved. Now humans fight in the armies
of their masters to save themselves from annihilation. At least,
that's what the propaganda insists is true. What the layers of lies
keep hidden, is how badly the new war is going for the people of
earth. Now it's Dylan Kane's turn to blast into the heavens and join
the battle, but what his masters don't know, is that by putting a
weapon in his hands, they're giving him the key to unlocking his hopes
of freedom. When the railgun slugs are tearing through his ship, and
the vacuum is sucking the life out of his wounded friends, will
Dylan's years of repressed rage turn into enough bravery to make his
dream come true?

